# What's the odd one out?

Tags: code-golf, source-layout

You are to write a program which outputs a single positive integer \$n\$. The integer may have leading zeros and whitespace, and/or trailing whitespace.

Then, choose a positive integer \$m > 1\$. When the program is repeated exactly \$m\$ times, it should output \$m \times n\$ (and only \$m\times n\$). When repeated any number of times other than \$m\$, it should output \$n\$ (and only \$n\$).

You may choose the value of \$m\$, so long as it is a positive integer greater than 1.

In this context, "repeated \$m\$ times" means that the whole program is repeated \$m\$ times, rather than each character. For example, repeating `abcde` \$4\$ times yields  `abcdeabcdeabcdeabcde`.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code (not repeated \$m\$ times) in bytes wins.

---

For example, if your program is `print 5` which outputs 5, and you choose \$m = 3\$, then:

- `print 5` should output 5
- `print 5print 5` should output 5
- `print 5print 5print 5` should output 15
- `print 5print 5print 5print 5` should output 5
- `print 5print 5print 5print 5print 5` should output 5
- etc.

Comment: Are functions allowed?

Comment: @Jonah So long as they follow the rules, yes

Comment: Huh, I accidentally chose the same n and m as the example. Spooky!

Comment: In my country zero is both positive and negative (we use the term strictly positive for >0), can `n` be zero?

Comment: @Kaddath If n is zero, then the program always outputs 0, no matter \$m\$, so no

Comment: true, I had not thought of that, anyway I gave up this idea because of PHP boringly outputs an empty string instead of zero if you try to echo false or null (while outputting 1 for true)

Comment: If our language does not support numbers, is outputting the next best thing allowed (outputting a stack where the length denotes a positive integer)?

Comment: @user Coukd you give me an example of such a language?

Comment: Can we write to stderr after the number is printed out?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Yes (and I think a lot of answers already do so), so long as it still "works" as specified when repeated

Comment: Is reading your own code a standard disallowed loophole? Or is that only for quine challenges?

Comment: @user253751 Only for Quine challenges

Comment: Since most answers choose m=2 or could be easily modified to do so, this is basically a duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/177881/just-twice-is-nice

Comment: @AaronMiller No matter the type of language, multiplying is defined in the question: concatenating \$n\$ programs together. [This](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/PzEpmSslNe3/fwA) multiplied by 3 would be [this](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/PzEpmSslNQ2V@v8fAA), not [this](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/PzEpGYK4UlLTIOj/fwA)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Oh well, guess I'll have to figure out a different way of solving it. Sorry I kept making and deleting comments, I couldn't get it to format how I wanted it.

Answer (score 9):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 16 bytes

```r
T=a=1+!T;T=T-1;a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8Q20dZQWzHEOsQ2RNfQOvF/Ua5GiCaXskJQakFqYklqikJJeWZyKhe6OnQ@F4Y@Y4WSzNzUYoI6CZtkQqZJGH4DAA)

Works with \$n=1\$ and \$m=2\$.

---

Previous version:

### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>24</s> <s>23</s> <s>21</s> 19 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to Dominic van Essen

```r
T=a=1+0^T^2;T=T-1;a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8Q20dZQ2yAuJM7IOsQ2RNfQOvF/Ua5GiCaXskJQakFqYklqikJJeWZyKhcWpViEuDB0GyuUZOamFhOpnygjTSg1Epu3AQ)

Works with \$n=1\$ and \$m=2\$. This uses the fact that

\$0^k = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } k=0\\0& \text { otherwise.}\end{cases}\$

Therefore, when the code is repeated \$k\$ times, we output \$1+0^{(2-k)^2}\$, which is worth \$2\$ when \$k=2\$, and \$1\$ otherwise.

Comment: [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8nWyDrR1lDbIE4jyTZJ11AzDsj/r6wQlFqQmliSmqJQUp6ZnMqFVRl2vQA)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Neat, thanks!

Comment: [19 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8Q20dZQ2yAuJM7IOsQ2RNfQOvF/Ua5GiCaXskJQakFqYklqikJJeWZyKhcWpViEuDB0GyuUZOamFhOpnygjTSg1Epu3AQ)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>27</s> <s>20</s> 18 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to Robin Ryder, and -2 bytes thanks to pajonk*

```r
b=a=3^!(F=F+1)-3;a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qvrJCfl6qQnF9QqZBfWlJQWlKsYPg/yTbR1jhOUcPN1k3bUFPX2DoRqK6kPB@kLjO1GKpSwZCrKFfDTZMLUzmmCBcX0ISMotRUNDOMSTADu6lp@aVF6A5TgJiqQKaxOCzKLEuluUXYrc7LzBsIq6kl8h8A)

n=1, m=3 (or trivially for any m up to 9 for same bytes...)

Comment: [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qvrJCfl6qQnF9QqZBfWlJQWlKsYPg/yTbRNiEzLUGj2s3WTduwVtdIx1DHSNM68f9/AA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @RobinRyder - Thanks! That inspired me to get rid of 5 more, too...!

Comment: Shouldn't this work for second approach? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qvrJCfl6qQnF9QqZBfWlJQWlKsYPg/yTbR1jhOUcPN1k3bUFPX2DoRqK6kPB@kLjO1GKpSwZCrKFfDTZMLUzmmCBcX0ISMotRUNDOMSTADu6lp@aVF6A5TgJiqQKaxOCzKLEuluUXYrc7LzBsIq6kl8h8A "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @pajonk - Thanks!  That's amazing - I never would have thought that the operator precedence could allow that!  It *looks* so wrong, but works!  Cool.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>77</s> <s>50</s> <s>46</s> <s>43</s> <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```python
input(1+(len([*open(__file__)])==2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzOvoLREw1BbIyc1TyNaK78ASMXHp2XmpMbHa8Zq2toaaWpy/f8PAA)

Simply counts the number of lines of the code and returns 2 if it is 2 and one otherwise. The `x` is not defined and causes a runtime error immediately after and ends the program.

$$n=1, m=2$$

Thanks to *ChartZ Belatedly* for -27 bytes, *FryAmTheEggman* for -3 bytes, *pxeger* for -4 bytes and *dingledooper* for -2 bytes.

Comment: [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EI9pQxyg2Oic1TyO/AEjEx6dl5qTGx2vqFaUmpmhoatraGhoYxGpaG@gbWP//DwA) using the same trick

Comment: Changing from indexing to computing a power saves enough to get [47 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69Ew0hLSyMnNU8jvwBIxMenZeakxsdr6hWlJqZoaGra2lqaaGpaG@gbWP//DwA).

Comment: 36 by outputting via exit code and counting lines: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P7Uis0RDIyc1TyNaK78ASMXHp2XmpMbHa8Zq2toaaWobanL9/w8A "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @pxeger the counting lines is smart, but I believe by output the OP means standard output only so using exit code for that is probably not allowed.

Comment: You can use `input()` to get [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzOvoLREw1BbIyc1TyNaK78ASMXHp2XmpMbHa8Zq2toaaWpy/f8PAA).

Comment: @ManishKundu disagree; "outputs" allows any [standard](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447) I/O method [by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1326)

Answer (score 6):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 26

n=3, m=2

```bash
trap echo\ $[++a-2?3:6] 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6QosUAhNTkjP0ZBJVpbO1HXyN7YyixWwYDr/38A)

[Try it online!Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6QosUAhNTkjP0ZBJVpbO1HXyN7YyixWwYALt8z//wA)

[Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6QosUAhNTkjP0ZBJVpbO1HXyN7YyixWwYCLHJn//wE)

Answer (score 5):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 22 bytes, \$n=1\$, \$m=2\$

```powershell
+!$x+!(++$x-2)-!($x-3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X1tRpUJbUUNbW6VC10hTV1EDSBtr/v8PAA)

[Try it online!Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X1tRpUJbUUNbW6VC10hTV1EDSBtrYhf9/x8A)

[Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X1tRpUJbUUNbW6VC10hTV1EDSBtrkiL6/z8A)

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 39 bytes, \$n=1\$, \$m=2\$

```powershell
1+((gc $PSCommandPath).Count-eq2);exit
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BbQyM9WUElINg5Pzc3MS8lILEkQ1PPOb80r0Q3tdBI0zq1IrOE6/9/AA)

## PowerShell 7, 39 bytes, \$n=1\$, \$m=2\$

```powershell
(gc $PSCommandPath).Count-eq2?2:1;exit
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 bytes

```
|d1=^
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7Cd1%3D%5E&i=)

[Run and debug itRun and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7Cd1%3D%5E%7Cd1%3D%5E&i=)

[Run and debug itRun and debug itRun and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7Cd1%3D%5E%7Cd1%3D%5E%7Cd1%3D%5E&i=)

This works for `m = 2, n = 1`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 bytes

```
⎚⊞υω×1⁼³Ｌυ5
```

\$n=5\$, \$m=3\$. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9jaGFyY29hbP//4o6a4oqez4XPicOXMeKBvMKz77ysz4U1//8) [Try it online!Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9jaGFyY29hbP//4o6a4oqez4XPicOXMeKBvMKz77ysz4U1//8) [Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R36xHXfPOt57vPDzd8FHjnkOb3@9Zc77VlFTx//8B) [Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R36xHXfPOt57vPDzd8FHjnkOb3@9Zc77VlFri//8DAA) Explanation:

```
⎚
```

Clear the canvas of output from the previous copy.

```
⊞υω
```

Track the number of copies.

```
×1⁼³Ｌυ
```

If that's 3 then print a `1`.

```
5
```

Always print a `5`.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, <s>65</s> <s>60</s> <s>57</s> <s>46</s> 45 bytes, \$n = 1, m = 5\$

```
var i=-~i;setTimeout(_=>i=i&&alert(i^5?1:5));
```

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563).*

*Saved 11 bytes thanks to [user81655](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46855)*

*Saved 1 byte thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602)*

By itself:

```js
var i=-~i;setTimeout(_=>i=i&&alert(i^5?1:5));
```

Repeated 5 times:

```js
var i=-~i;setTimeout(_=>i=i&&alert(i^5?1:5));var i=-~i;setTimeout(_=>i=i&&alert(i^5?1:5));var i=-~i;setTimeout(_=>i=i&&alert(i^5?1:5));var i=-~i;setTimeout(_=>i=i&&alert(i^5?1:5));var i=-~i;setTimeout(_=>i=i&&alert(i^5?1:5));
```

Comment: `this.i=-~this.i` should save 3 bytes.

Comment: You should also be able to remove the `this.` at the start

Comment: `b&&(b=alert(i^5?1:5))` can become `b=b&&alert(i^5?1:5)`

Comment: Also you could replace `b` with `i` so you don't have to declare `,b=1`

Comment: If you're going to assume a browser environment for `alert` and `setTimeout`, then you can use `top` to save a byte.

Comment: `var i=-~i;` is an alternative way to save a byte.

Comment: @Neil Nice one.

Answer (score 4):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) `-F`, 21 bytes, \$n=1\$, \$m=4\$

```sh
bye `wc -l<$0`-5?1:4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@G9jo@6qbpf2P6kyVSGhPFlBN8dGxSBB19Te0MqE678rV1VxhoKum0Ial42NjYr9fwA)

[Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@G9jo@6qbpf2P6kyVSGhPFlBN8dGxSBB19Te0MqEi0LB/65cVcUZCrpuCmlcNjY2Kvb/AQ)

Note the trailing newline. Outputs via exit code.

Answer (score 4):

## Factor, 172 bytes, n = 2, m = 4

Let's see some love for the [language of the month](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20824/language-of-the-month-for-march-2021-factor?cb=1).

```
 USING: prettyprint namespaces init math io kernel ; IN: main 0 1 set-global
1 get-global 1 + 1 set-global [ 1 get-global 4 = [ 8 ] [ 2 ] if . flush ] 2 add-shutdown-hook !
```

(The leading space before `USING:` is significant, and so is the lack of newline at the end)

We store a simple counter in a global variable (global variables in Factor are, by convention, symbols, but there's no actual requirement, so our global variable is named the integer `1`). Then the part of our code that "repeats" simply increments this global. We register a shutdown hook that does the final checks for us. The fact that we register the hook several times is irrelevant, because we give it the same name each time (this name, incidentally, is the integer `2`; once again, Factor is happy to accept a very loose definition of "name").

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYmxCsIwGAZ3n@JzlootDlJxli5dipM4/DZJE5omIfmL@PQxk9Dl4O4UjexjzngMXX9vEaJk/oZoHMPRIlOgUSYYZxgLsYbxmGV00uKKrm9LNA4n1EiSq8n6N9ldjekv5Rw2F09s/hm3ki54FTaFRuEIZdekizQgIaqkVxb@4yrt/Yx9zj8)

[Try it online!Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1Y6xCsIwFEV3v@I6S8QWB6k4S5cu4iQOsUmb0PQlJK@IXx8zCf0ElwP3nOUOsmcfc8b91nbXBiFq5k@IlhgkZ52C7HWCJcuYJRtYj0lH0g5ntF1TpCUcUCFpFqPzL@k2FcbfKGW3qnhg1Y@4FHXCs7AutAP2GNySTBk1pFIimYWVf5Mw3k/Y/tPXnL8)

[Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7Y6xCsIwFEV3v@I6S8QWB6k4S5cuxUkcYpM0oWkSklfEr4@ZhH6Am8uFc85yFR/Ix5xx69vu2iBESfQO0TiC47NMgQ8ywThDmDlpGI9JRictzmi7pkjjcECFJImN1j@53VQYv1DKblVxx6ofcSnqhEfZuqxR2EPZJekCNbgQLOmFhH85pr2fsP1//c3XnD8)

[Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7Y6xCsIwFEV3v@I6S8QWB6k4S5cuxUkcYpM0oWkSklfEr4@ZhP5DlwvnnOUqPpCPOePRt929QYiS6BuicQTHZ5kCH2SCcYYwc9IwHpOMTlpc0XZNkcbhhApJEhutf3O7qzD@oZTDquKJVT/jVtQFr7J1WaNwhLJL0gVqcCFY0gsJ/3FMez9hv33dvub8Aw)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>6</s> <s>5</s> 4 bytes, \$ n=1, m=2 \$

-1 thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen

```
.gΘ>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fL/3cDLv//wE)

Comment: Can't your second solution be 4 bytes by replacing the `1+` with `>`?

Comment: It can, I'm not sure how I didn't notice that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Java 6, <s>120</s> 77 bytes, \$n=1, m=2\$

```
enum A{A;{System.out.print(new java.io.File("A.java").length()==154?2:1);}}//
```

*Saved 43 bytes thanks to [Olivier Grégoire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16236).*

Comment: I think usually if you assume a file name you need to include it in your byte score (also you can use a name of `a` I think)

Comment: @CommandMaster Since the interface is named `Main`, it cannot be run unless the file name is `Main.java`.

Comment: @iota I just tried that and it seems to work.

Comment: then can't you name the interface a?

Comment: @user How did you run it?

Comment: @CommandMaster That's a good point. TIO seems to always use "Main.java" as the filename, though.

Comment: `javac A.java` and then `java Main`

Comment: @user I see. The interface needs to be public.

Comment: @iota Does it? I managed to run it with just `interface Main{static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(new java.io.File("A.java").length()==226?2:1);}}//` (I think that was your original answer)

Comment: @user No, I changed my answer to add `public`.

Comment: 1. Your program can be shortened for Java versions 5 & 6: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140181/16236 2. You can get rid of the `public` as Java allows running it if you call `java Main.java` (yes, without compiling). 3. You can name the class `A`. All in all, you can reduce to 92 bytes: `enum A{A;{System.out.print(new java.io.File("A.java").length()==184?2:1);System.exit(0);}}//` You don't need to have it running on TIO to have a valid submission.

Comment: Also, usually, Codegolf rules allow you to write to `stderr` after you've output the correct value, so this 77 bytes solution would work: `enum A{A;{System.out.print(new java.io.File("A.java").length()==154?2:1);}}//`. Then, running `java A.java` on Java 5 or 6 will yield the correct output.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @user253751 I haven't seen any rule that forbids that. The [Loopholes that are forbidden by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/99986) question does not mention this except for quines. The [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220464/99986) to this question also reads its source code.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>8</s> 6 bytes, \$n=1\$, \$m=2\$

Works because Javascript numbers [don't overflow from positive to negative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054891/does-javascript-handle-integer-overflow-and-underflow-if-yes-how).
Essentially J is incremented to infinity, 2 is output only on the case of two repetitions.

```js
J°?1:2 // J is a builtin variable that equals -1 at first.
J°     // If J++ is truthy (-1, 1, 2, etc)
  ?1:2 // output 1, otherwise 2.
```

[Try it here.](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=SrA/MToy&input=)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 40 bytes

```javascript
0;i=-~this.i,{get x(){print(i-3?1:3)}}.x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY3BCoMwEETvfsUeE6xB8VKaBn/FELftitUQlyAE@@tpPM2DGd7MNtrdBfLcxHt227ozuG1CMDDmVpNpfvyhXdEtvZHhEDL5QCsLavqhe/TyPNWRR8WBvkLq6rUFEEtZzsXQ6hJPA90FdS0hVQATlhqBdGGMdhHXnQro0bKYZXGc@Q8)

Uses the same trick as [my solution the other day](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220447/46855). The core idea is putting the `print()` behind a getter function. If the `.x` property is accessed it will print the result. This is placed at the end of the generated code so that it accesses `.x` on the last iteration but when concatenated it becomes `.x0` (does not access `.x`).

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 26 bytes, \$n=1\$, \$m=2\$

```javascript
(x=>x?y=>y?g=z=>z?g:1:2:1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcxBDsIgEEDRPaeY5UwaibhEgauUIBIMlgawaWs8OzZx9Tcv/2kXW12JcztN@e57ze/iPCgYO65Kr2ZTejNB7UrvJkghL1JQH3kr8YXE2CMXwHh4cYUINxDno8NA8GEALk81J89TDugXm/B/58XP3jaMREjEvqz/AA)

Is this valid? I'm not quite sure...

---

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 28 bytes, \$n=1\$, \$m=2\$

```javascript
f=x=>((f+'').length==54)+1//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcxBDsIgEEDRPaeYXWdCpJLoSvEsJTitKC0EsNEYz45NXP3V@3e72uKyT3VXkr9ynuPy4Hcr8Zkdg4GhjeZlLoij7DpSgZep3ow5Hkjqvm@DqtnPSEKMMQP6TegTeDiD3m@VkuAjAFxcSgysQpyQVxvw/1eZE9uKngiJxLf9AA)

Another similar answer [(requires Firefox 86**-**)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1579792)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 20 bytes, \$n=1\$, \$m=2\$

```
a=b=1;a+=1;b+=a==3;b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPhfrGCroKSk9D/RNsnW0DpRG0gkadsm2toaWyf9B0pEG1ql5qXoGsZycaXlFylkKmTmKRhamXIpgEBBUWZeSU6eRqYmKr84Dl0ktSwxR8M3tSRRryCxqDgVrEITTY0mF9Cm/wA)

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>38</s> 34 bytes \$n=1\$ \$m=2\$

```php
<?=count(file(__FILE__))!=3?:2;
//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42Ob80r0QjLTMnVSM@3s3TxzU@XlNT0dbY3srImktf//9/AA)

This hacky solution relies on getting the current code's first line and testing the length is 76 (38 * 2). Works as a standalone but needs the `//` to comment any repetitions of the program so that only one output is displayed. Also in ternary conditions `a?b:c`, if `b` is missing, the value of `a` is used, and in PHP `true` is displayed as `1`.

EDIT: saved 4 bytes by counting the lines of code instead of length of the first line. Notice the newline *before* the comment

Answer (score 2):

## Brainfuck, <sup>268</sup>264 characters / <sup>101</sup>99 bytes, n=1, m=2

```
    ++>+ Init
    [->+>+<<]>>[-<<+>>]< Copy second into third
    [-<<->>]<< Check if equal
        [ If not equal
            [-] Reset first
            +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
            .
            ------------------------------------------------- Output 1
            >>>-<<< Set a flag saying that this cycle was passed
        ]
        >>>+ Change the flag
        [ If the flag is nonzero (meaning the previous cycle was not passed)
            [-] Reset the flag
            ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
            .
            -------------------------------------------------- Output 2
        ]
    <[-]<<[-] Reset first and third
```

[Try it online!](https://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/#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)

This can take a while to run, so set the delay to minimum if you want to test it.

Definitely not a good golfing language, but it was interesting to write just for the sake of it.

(This challenge is impossible to complete in BF as it's stated because repeated code will always produce a multiple-char output, so in this solution the answer is the last output char)

Edit: I'm completely brain dead and forgot this is code golf, so I wrote the last lines in a really weird way. Corrected, saved 4 chars.

Comment: Can you assume an env supporting `\r` or `\b` to erase last output?

Comment: @l4m2 I don't really know if that works in bf

Answer (score 2):

## [Grok](https://github.com/AMiller42/Grok-Language), 31 bytes, n=1, m=2

```
`  j
ljq
11z
+=1
 {k
j2`h
`lzq
```

Note the single trailing newline. Program was multiplied with `cat odd1out >> odd2out`. At first I thought I would have to rework my solution because of how programs need to be multiplied, but then I realized I could just turn it on its side.